# How to choose which connection to use for SSH

Tags: network, wifi, ssh

I have an ethernet connection which is restricted for a lot of ports (the most annyoing is port 22 -ssh- ).

I now have a Wifi connection which is unrestricted.

I want to tell to my mac, **each time i use the port 22 via the terminal, to use the WIFI and in the other case, to use the Ethernet connexion**.

Is there a way to do this ? (MBP Retina  end 2013, OSX 10.9.4)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is :

```
ssh -b bind_address_of_wifi_ip ......
```

Comment: how did you find that solution?

Comment: It is in man ssh